# Plot.ly Pandas scatter plot text from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a chart that I'm rendering using Plot.ly from a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10), 
                  'd':list(range(10)), 'e':list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10])})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10), 
                  'd':list(range(10)), 'e':list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10])})

fig = {
    'data': [
        {'x': df1.x, 
         'y': df1.y, 
         'text': df1.d, 
         'mode': 'markers', 
         'name': 'Example 1',
        },
        {'x': df2.x, 
         'y': df2.y, 
         'text': df2.d, 
         'mode': 'markers', 
         'name': 'Example 2',
        }
    ]
}

py.iplot(fig, filename='couldbeanything')
```

And this draws a nice chart with the dataframe's column 'd' used for the data labels. 
[image: plot.ly display]

But actually I want to use a composite of two columns for the data labels (let's say d and e). Is this possible? I've tried passing a list or a dict and neither appear to work.

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to create a new text field and reference that using two other columns that exist in that dataframe. Have you considered generating a column that is formating as you want, and then using that as the labels? For instance, `df['text'] = df['id'] + df['description']` or something similar? Is there a reason why that won't work?

Comment: Can you give a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see how your current output differs from what you desire?

Comment: @Projski that works, thanks! I actually had to do `df['text'] = df['id'].map(str) + df['description']`